# What are good examples of websites built using Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

What are good examples of websites built using Yii Framework.

I wonder if it is being used ready in a large scale.

Comment: This is a good example of website which is built with Yii framework - [Raritysoft.com](http://www.raritysoft.com/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a sub-board in the Yii forums listing [Yii-powered applications](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/forum/14-yii-powered-applications/). The two big ones I see pinned are [stay.com](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/3450-stay-com/) and [realself.com](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/13717-realselfcom-15-million-monthly-visitors/).

Comment: stay.com certainly shows what yii is capable of! Have installed and about to try the blog tutorial, will see if this changes my plans for a site refactor using codeigniter.

Answer (score 2):

You have a forum dedicated to your question.
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/forum/14-yii-powered-applications/